# Is it alright to have 2 async await function inside the useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have these async await codes: Would it cause problems if I have 2 async await function inside my useEffect hook?

```
const [size, setSize] = useState(0)

const getData1 = async () => {
  const citiesRef = firestore.collection("users");
  const snapshot = await citiesRef
    .where("item.itemName", "==", selected)
    .where("selected","==", true)
    .get();
  setSize(snapshot.size)
};

const [size2, setSize2] = useState(0)

const getData2 = async () => {
  const citiesRef = firestore.collection("users");
  const snapshot = await citiesRef
    .where("item.itemName", "==", selected)
    .where("selected","==", false)
    .get();
  setSize2(snapshot.size)
};

 useEffect(() => {
    if (selected) {
      getData1();
      getData2();
    }
  }, [selected]);
```

Comment: I'm not aware of any issues but you can make those requests in a single function as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be fine as long as you are not blocking the process by making the function inside the useEffect async and awaiting in there like:

```
 useEffect( async() => {
    if (selected) {
      await getData1();
      await getData2();
    }
  }, [selected]);
```

The functions you are calling in useEffect are returning promises instantly (non-blocking) that later resolve, the example I provide makes the useEffect function wait for the promises to resolve (blocking) before ending the function call.

Comment: Ohh alright. Thank you for the explanation. Is it also possible to have multiple function inside the useEffect, maybe up to 5 functions I think?

Comment: I don't see why not, as long as they are non blocking. But I would personally just write an updateHandler function that is called once the component updates that handles all of the functions you would want to run during an update. Its best not to get too messy with the useEffect function, rather just allow it to invoke the gritty stuff.